# Which MARC Format is This

Tags: php, marc

I have a bunch of marc records in database which looks like this

```
    001    00000074 
003 DLC
005 20050901073116.0
008 730629s1899    maua          000 1 eng  
010   $a   00000074 
020   $a0836932722
035   $a(OCoLC)647986
040   $aDLC$cOKentU$dOCoLC$dDLC
042   $apremarc
050 00$aPZ3.S918$bLo$aPS3537.T845
100 1 $aStringer, Arthur,$d1874-1950.
245 14$aThe loom of destiny$c[by] Arthur J. Stringer ...
260   $aBoston,$bSmall, Maynard & Company,$c1899.
300   $a5 p. l., 3-208 p.$billus.$c17 cm.
500   $aSome of these stories were originally published in Ainslee's magazine.
505 0 $aPremonitions.--The undoing of Dinney Crockett.--The fly in the ointment.--The iron age.--The king who lost his crown.--Life's loaded die.--The crucible of character.--The essentials of aristocracy.--The honour of the house of Hummerley.--Thicker than water.--Instruments of Eros.--An essay in equality.--The heart's desire.--Not in utter nakedness.
```

I am trying to get to work with it with php marc pear library , but  with no success. The problem is the format is guess, which I cannot identify. Could anywone maybe help to identify which exact format is this and how to parse the data out of it nicely?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like mnemonic MARC without the equal signs at the beginning of the line. 
You can try using [marcedit](http://marcedit.reeset.net/) or custom code to convert that into marc communications format which can be parsed by anything.

note that in the record above you're missing the leader which might be a problem when rebuilding the new record format.

Comment: seems mnemonic marc21 either to me but no  php lib could parse ( Leader part was there, I have cut it during pasting here)

Comment: You cant parse it like that. try maybe concatenating all fields to one line and parsing that. marc communication format is a record very much like mnemonic but where all the record is one line (no line breaks). maybe that will work?